# g-wan error unknown SIGSEGV

Tags: g-wan

I have problem using g-wan. When try to download large file, I got this error message :

```
Signal        : 11:Unknown SIGSEGV problem
Signal src    : 128:.
errno         : 0
Thread        : 1
Code   Pointer: 0000004081a8 (module:gwan, function:??, line:0)
Access Address: 000000000000

Registers     : EAX=7f1dbc0afa4e CS=00000033 EIP=0000004081a8 EFLGS=000000010287
            EBX=7f1dc24af000 SS=d5ab0400 ESP=7f1dd59acd30 EBP=7f1dbc0afa4e
            ECX=ffe3e5a1746a4230 DS=d5ab0400 ESI=1c997c47a33a4e FS=00000033
            EDX=1c1a5e8b984000 ES=d5ab0400 EDI=7f1dbc0afa3e CS=00000033

Module         :Function        :Line # PgrmCntr(EIP)  RetAddress  FramePtr(EBP)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Segmentation fault
```

I tried to use centos 7 (64 bit),6.5 (64 bit),ubuntu 10.04 (64 bit) but still got this error.

I used 1GB RAM with 1 core.

Anybody know how to solve this issue ?

Thanks for all

Comment: how "large" is this file, and which version of g-wan are you running? Also, try http://gwan.com/faq#crash on the main.c connection handler.

Comment: Linux LIBC changes break "old" programs periodically. So you constantly have to adapt and recompile the old program to continue using it normally... or to create and use your own (stable) Linux distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Anybody know how to solve this issue ?

Yes, upgrade to a more recent version. Yours in almost 2 years old and newer versions work fine.

Comment: I'm using this link 
http://gwan.com/archives/gwan_linux64-bit.tar.bz2
From gwan download page. 
I have no idea which one is the latest version.

Comment: The latest release was compiled 2 days ago. Registered users get access to these updates. We stopped G-WAN public updates to focus on Global-WAN.com our G-WAN-based Cloud.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Gil,
May I know how can I register ? Because I'm not able to see how, in g-wan website.

Comment: @I-Coder to become registered, you need to [buy a support plan](http://gwan.com/buy). Just keep in mind that you're buying their _support_ and not the software.